# Ruby On Rails: Как изменить папку для создания моделей в шаблонах генератора scaffold?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Всем привет.
Вот я генерирую `rails g scaffold admin/category name` 
Модель создается в папке `models/admin/category.rb`

Все отлично, но как сделать так чтобы из всего генерируемого скафолдом только модель создавалась в папке `model/category.rb` ?
И в названии модели было без указания namespace, и вместо `Admin::Category`, было просто `Category`

Можно так сделать? Если да то как?

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы генерировалась одна модель

```
rails generate model admin/category title:string text:text
```

Lля того, чтобы не было `admin` генерируйте

```
rails generate model category title:string text:text
```

Answer (score 1):

Как и сказала @alina-ruby если вам не подходит scaffold, который генерит контроллер, въю, и модель, то генерируйте отдельно модель или контроллер, 
например: 
 `rails generate model(controller) category`

Старайтесь избегать названий как "admin/category", лучше "admin_category" и вообще старайтесь "_" в названиях моделей и контроллерах не употреблять. [Гайд](https://github.com/arbox/ruby-style-guide/blob/master/README-ruRU.md) в помощь.

для отмены генерации вместо "g"(generatre) вставьте "d"(destroy или delete)